# My drag and drop file upload is not working in IE and Microsoft Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, drag-and-drop

I have written a code which implements drag and drop functionality for file upload. This code is working fine in Google Chrome, Safari and Firefox but it is not working in Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer.Whenever I try to drag the file,instead of adding the file in the  , the file itself opens up in the browser. How can I fix this?
Here is the code -

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        .container{
          background-color:#00B3E6;
          width:800px;
          margin:auto;
          height:450px;
        }
        .header{
          color:white;
          text-align:center;
          padding:20px;
        }
        body{
          color:white;
        }
        
               .zoneupload { position: relative; width: 300px; background: #FFFFFF; border: 5px solid #018fb7; padding: 10px; margin:auto; }
               .zoneupload .fichier { height: 160px; width: 300px; border: none; -webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance:none; background: white; margin-top:7px; opacity:0; -moz-opacity:0; }
               .zoneupload small {  position: absolute; margin: -90px 0 0 70px; color:black;}
               .zoneupload #send { position: absolute; right: 6px; bottom: 10px }
               .text{margin:auto; color:white; text-align:center; }
               #linkupload{ margin:auto; width:280px; }
        </style>
        
        </head>
        
        <body>
          <div class="container">
            <h2 class="header"> Zscaler App - Decrypt Logs Utility </h2>
        <fieldset class="zoneupload">
               <form method="post" action="upload.php" name="upload" id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                       <input type="hidden" name="post" value="file">
                       <input type="file" name="userfile" id="fichier" class="fichier" onchange="display(this)" >
                       <input type="button" value="Upload" id="send" onclick="checkAndSend(this)">
                       <br>
                       <small><b>Browse for file or drop a file</b></small>
               </form>
        </fieldset>
        <br/>
        <p class='text' id="link">Drop in the white area</p>
        <br>
        <p class='text'>or</p>
        <br>
        <form action="linkupload.php" method="post" enctype="muiltipart/form-data" id="linkupload">
        <label><strong>Link:</strong></label> <input type="text" name="link" id="link">
        <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="checkAndSendLink(this)">
        </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function checkAndSend(input){
            var form=document.getElementById('upload');
            if(document.getElementById('fichier').value != ''){
              form.submit();
            }
            else{
              window.alert('Select a file');
            }
          }
        
          function checkAndSendLink(input){
            var form=document.getElementById('linkupload');
            if(document.getElementById('link').value != ''){
              form.submit();
            }else{
              window.alert('link field is empty');
            }
          }
        
          function display(input)
               { 
                var str=input.value;
                str=str.replace('C:\\fakepath\\','')
                document.getElementById('link').innerHTML=str;
               }
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
               $(document).on('dragover', '#fichier', function(e) {
                       e.preventDefault();
                       console.log('he');
        
               });
               
        
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Looks fine in Edge - the fact that it doesn't work in IE is not surprising. Best fix is to not advertise drap/drop when dealing with such a retarded browser :p